# What is an $n$ dimensional space?

Tags: spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, visualization

How an $n$ dimensional space looks like? Is it possible that we are really in a space of dimension greater than 3?

Comment: You've already asked this. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70190/

Comment: I am reminded of this: http://mathoverflow.net/a/1227/35977

Comment: Obvious Duplicate (by the OP) of [Some question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70190/) .

Comment: Research-level, seriously?

Answer (score 5):

We can only visualize three spatial dimensions because we live our lives in a three dimensional world. The possibility of a fourth spatial dimension is not something we can have any intuition on. It is of course possible that there is another spatial dimension, and that these "4-dimensional' creatures just never interacted with us.

For example, let's say you are a circle living on a piece of paper. You can move in 2 dimensions. You have no idea what a "third" spatial dimensional would look like. You just know up, down, left, and right. You would be even be able to conceive of being "above" the paper or "under" the paper. Unless, let's say a sphere comes along and jumps into your piece of paper. It would look like it came out of nowhere, and you would see a circle appearing getting bigger while the sphere is entering your plane, and when it's leaving your plane, it would disappear.

So if a "4-dimensional" object was to enter our space, it would just appear out of nowhere as a 3-dimensional object, and can easily disappear by jumping out of our space.

Answer (score 1):

Since our normal experience is with a three-dimensional world (four-dimensional with time (which answers your second question), but that's not a dimension we can move backwards and forwards in at will, so our experience there is limited) it is hard for us to picture what larger-dimensional space looks like.  We just don't think like that.  I tried to image what a larger-dimensional space would look like when I first started linear algebra and the math was generalized to dimensions larger than three and became incredibly frustrated at my failed attempts.  Eventually I realized that n-dimensional space wasn't beyond my experience, it just didn't represent the world I lived in as much.

For instance, for a business there are many factors that go in to how much profit they can make off a certain product: price, supply, demand, amount of advertising, type of advertising...the number of factors can be large.  Equations can be made to predict how much profit total will be made, with each of these factors being represented by a variable, or a separate dimension.  Then I realized that n-dimensional space would be similar.  Just because I can't picture in my head what a larger-dimensional space would look like doesn't mean I can't use and understand it: I'd have to think of it more mathematically than in pictures, just do the math and get the result, rather than trying to project the n-dimensional points onto the three-dimensional grid I live in.